# Were there Jedi/Sith who specialized in artillery?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, sith

Jedi and Sith are best known to either fight with a lightsaber on the ground or as starfighter pilots in space. Were there Jedi/Sith whose primary combat specialty was artillery (e.g. missile launchers, turbolaser turrets)?

Do not consider starfighters to be artillery for the purposes of this question. Here tanks can be regarded as mobile artillery.

Comment: Not my area of knowledge, but an order rather dedicated to preserving life where they can, and known for only taking up weapons of precision at great need, would probably balk at ranged, messy, collateral damage, explosions, etc.

Comment: Jedi are preservers of life, diplomats etc. They arent AOE specialists in long range mass murder.

Comment: My question also covered Sith... in which case Sith artillerists would be more probable than Jedi artillerists.

Comment: Artillery generally need some kind of other force out in front of them to keep them getting over-run by the enemy. With only 2 Sith at a time, you're not going to have whole Sith armies (or even squads) available to protect the Sith howitzer.

Comment: The Rule of Two was instituted post-Ruusan (1000 BBY onward); Sith artillerists would most likely have been fielded ca. 1000-5000 BBY.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Artillery, as a combat specialty, would be useless to a Jedi in almost all circumstances:

1. The Jedi are peacekeepers, not soldiers. With the galaxy at peace for a thousand years, there is no use for skills in artillery for direct combat involving oneself.
2. In (peacetime) missions where combat is anticipated, the Jedi are frequently in need of remaining covert and undercover. There aren't enough missions in the life of a Jedi to make having specialisation in artillery as one's preferred choice of combat a feasible option.
3. At most, knowledge of artillery would be useful not for bringing your own bombad cannon into battle, but to be able to operate random pieces of artillery lying around when you're being attacked - as demonstrated by Obi Wan during the Battle of Ryloth - or to train and advise rebels, for instance, in their operation to better resist oppressive regimes, a type of mission that was put into play during the Liberation of Onderon.

The Clone Wars was the first time in the Republic's history when specialisation in artillery may actually prove useful. However, no Jedi would have prepared for it because nobody saw the war coming. Any Jedi who started learning to specialise in it...well, let's just say Order 66 came down after only 3 years of war.

Editing this answer to cover areas I did not address:

- As I've already mentioned, during a thousand years of peace the Jedi have no need to specialise in artillery. It's good to know how to operate them, but not to select as your primary form of combat. Notwithstanding that artillery is not ideal within the context of personal combat in any circumstance, other answers have already indicated that artillery AOE causes too much collateral damage - highly undesirable for Jedi in combat missions who aim to kill and destroy only what is strictly necessary. More relevantly, Jedi may broadly specialise in technology or weapons technology, but not usually as specific as artillery, and definitely not for the reason of personal combat use.
- Likewise, the Sith operates in stealth and subtlety during the reign of the Rule of Two: artillery draws too much attention.
- During the Clone Wars, as you can see, the explanation for the Sith holds. As for the Jedi, their overarching priority is to bring about a swift end to the war and a return to peace even as the war drags on. Despite three years of war, it is not yet long enough to feel like a new norm. In my opinion, it takes a Jedi Initiate who grew up in war to contemplate specialising in artillery - it requires one to have never experienced peace to specialise in war.
- After the Empire, the New Jedi Order has focused on rebuilding their order. Their involvement in galactic strife of the period is minimal: The New Republic and its successors may ask for the Jedi to go on special missions, but they aren't formally involved in the battlefield. That's probably a result of lessons gleaned  from the Clone Wars. The Jedi's involvement are usually constrained to Jedi sites like Yavin, or in "I just happen to be there" circumstances as frequently happened in the Yuuzhan Vong crisis. In summary, the Jedi are in the process of recovery, and have withdrawn from formal involvement in warfare, something that's deemed to skirt too close to the dark side.
- Less is clear of those who call themselves Sith post-Empire. The Banite Order, the true Sith tracing their line unbroken to the very dawn of the first Sith that came from Korriban millennia ago, ended with Lumiya and Caedus' fall. They all used subtlety and proxy non-Force wielding soldiers. As for Darth Krayt's heretical One Sith, they did not involve themselves in warfare either: they manipulated the galaxy into fighting each other, then took over and continued to use existing armies to fight their wars.
- The most likely place to find artillery specialised Force wielders would be in the endless wars before it all ended at Ruusan. While I do not know names, I would say it is unlikely still. Like I said, its nature conflicts with the Jedi philosophy, while for the Sith they despise even more primitive weapons that do not utilise the supreme power of the dark side.

Comment: One would think that Jedi or Sith in the pre-Ruusan eras (especially 1000-5000 BBY) would have had Force-using artillerists among their ranks. Presumably Jedi and Sith of these eras would have had to work harder for their commands than in the Clone Wars. Your answer only covers post-Ruusan but prior to the classical era (0-4 ABY). Any indication of Jedi or Sith artillerists in the Yuuzhan Vong or One Sith eras?

Comment: The Jedi might have considered themselves peacekeepers in the *ideal*, but they certainly functioned as soldiers (even calling themselves generals). Also, three years should have been plenty of time for the Jedi to specialize in artillery if they'd desired it. Remember that neither the Jedi *or the Republic* saw the war coming (the Republic didn't have a standing army until the Senate approved the use of the GAR in Episode II), yet the Republic used tanks and artillery in the war.

Comment: Updated in response to the comments

Answer (score 2):

If you are counting the Death Star(s) and Starkiller base as artillery then to an extent yes.

Darth Sidious/Darth Vader used the Death Star as long range 'artillery' and Kylo Ren (and Snoke?) used Starkiller base as a more powerful long range 'artillery'.

Obviously these aren't artillery in terms of tanks and it isn't the main combat option for these characters. However we can bend the question a bit and say yes there have been from a certain point of view.

Comment: But neither of those pairs specialised in artillery. It was just their method for Galactic domination

Comment: @Edlothiad Which I mention in my answer: _it isn't their main combat option_

Answer (score 1):

**To the best of my knowledge no Jedi or Sith served primarily in a tank/artillery role in any era, either in canon or Legends. There's good reason to think no such Jedi or Sith exists: a Force-sensitive individual does not have a significant advantage over a Force-*in*sensitive individual in such a role.**

We see Jedi and Sith serving in an infantry role because of their ability to deflect blaster bolts with their lightsabers, their quick reflexes, and the ease in using the Force against other infantry (Force Push, Force Lightning, etc.). The Jedi/Sith ability to deflect blaster bolts (and send them back to their enemies) is a *huge* advantage, especially in a galaxy where a single blaster bolt can take a fully-armored clonetrooper out of the fight.

We also see Jedi and Sith in a fighter pilot role because their quick reflexes still give them a significant advantage for them over Force-insensitive pilots (e.g. in a [dogfight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogfight), or when a quick reaction is required to evade enemy fire). The Jedi had the [Delta-7 starfighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Delta-7_Aethersprite-class_light_interceptor) and [Eta-2 starfighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eta-2_Actis-class_light_interceptor) built exclusively for themselves to take advantage of their Force abilities:

> The Delta-7’s designers worked with the Jedi to create a starfighter for pilots with Force-aided reflexes, stripping down the fighters’ systems and making their controls as responsive as possible.
>
> <sub>**[Delta-7 Jedi Starfighter](http://www.starwars.com/databank/delta-7-jedi-starfighter), Star Wars Databank**</sub>

Additionally, piloting a starfighter is still physically demanding (e.g. pilots can experience [G-forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force)) so a Jedi or Sith pilot would be better able to endure such stresses.

A Jedi or Sith has no such advantage in a tank/artillery role, however. Such vehicles are designed to protect their occupants against small arms, so the Jedi/Sith ability to deflect blaster bolts is not necessary in such a role. Their quick reflexes aren't really needed, either -- the ability to fire on a target is often more dependent on the turret's traversal rate (which is relatively slow) than the gunner's ability to react and pull the trigger. Heavy guns like tanks and artillery are generally used against bigger and more armored targets, too -- which are usually easier to hit, even by a Force-insensitive gunner. This is particularly true in *Star Wars*, where [naval combat tends to take place at close quarters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/why-do-capital-ships-in-star-wars-engage-at-close-range):

[image: close quarters naval combat]

and [some mobile artillery](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Self-Propelled_Heavy_Artillery) requires line of sight to hit a target:

[image: SPHA]

**A Jedi or Sith is a [force multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_multiplication) in an infantry or pilot role due to their Force-sensitivity, but not in a tank/artillery role. Hence it is actually a waste of resources to use a Jedi or Sith as a tanker/artilleryman instead of an infantryman or pilot.**

Note: some have suggested that the Jedi wouldn't serve in a tank/artillery role due to ideological objections (they are self-professed "guardians of the peace"). I find this explanation unsatisfactory for the following reasons:

- The Jedi serving in war took the rank of [Jedi General](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_General/Legends) (a distinctly military title), commanded clone troopers in the Clone Wars, fought in infantry and fighter pilot roles, etc..  While the Jedi *ideal* may have been to serve only as peacekeepers, at some point we have to admit that the Jedi functioned as soldiers in certain circumstances. If they were willing to fight as infantry and fighter pilots in such instances, there's no reason to think they'd object to a tanker/artilleryman role if such a role was useful for them.
- The Sith would presumably have no such objections, yet the Sith do not seem to serve as tankers/artillerymen (granted, there are usually far fewer Sith than Jedi due to the Rule of Two).

Comment: The Rule of Two was instituted ca. 1000 BBY (Darth Bane, Ruusan Reformations); Force-users were more abundant on the battlefields of 1000-5000 BBY than in the Clone Wars or any conflict happening thereafter (Yuuzhan Vong, One Sith).

Comment: @NSERCProtester Yes, that's why I said "there are **usually** far fewer Sith...due to the Rule of Two". I'm still not aware of any Jedi or Sith artillerymen in an era in which Force-users were more abundant.

Comment: These are mostly good points regarding vehicles. I got the impression that the asker was including hand-held heavy weapons, like an AT-4, but maybe not. Either way, a Jedi would certainly be more accurate with their shots than a non-Jedi, at the least.